# Filter list by multiple perimeters in one query

Tags: c#

I want to query a directory, I only want to collect from the directory files which are text based files. (CSV, TXT, INI)

Other file types I plan to ignore.

I'm trying to do this in one query using `Directory.GetFiles`, which works find if I query one file type at a time. I want to do this in one query.

This works fine for only accepting TXT files:

```
var sourceFolderContents = Directory.GetFiles(folder).ToList().Where(x => x.Split('.').Last().ToUpper().Equals("TXT"));
```

but how can I add an AND 'CSV' AND 'INI' to this so that sourceFolderContents has a list of CSV, TXT and INI files within?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var extensions = new string[]{".TXT",".CSV",".INI"};
var sourceFolderContents = Directory.GetFiles(folder)
        .Where(f=>extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f).ToUpper()))
        .ToList();
```

**NOTE**: When using `GetFiles`, you should consider setting the permission using `SetAccessControl`, otherwise in somecase there may be some unauthorized or access denied exception.

Comment: I don't seem to be able get you example (which makes perfect sense now I see it) to work. No files are return, however using my method or even just GetFiles I can get a file listing.

Comment: ignore me. I must have missed the edit when the '.' was added to the string array. Thank you

Comment: @Damo That means there are not files ends with `TXT`, `CSV` or `INI`, you should check your folder again to be sure, it's very strange because the query is simple enough.